# No result is happening for this Web3.js call

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const web3 = new Web3("ws://localhost:7545");


const contract_address = "0x7484d32e8911817702c5d7c764dBF7e592000b415";


async function web3Contract() {
    const contract_abi = fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/Bottle.json', 'utf8')
    const abi = JSON.parse(contract_abi).abi;
    // console.log(abi);
    const Bottle = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_address);
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    await Bottle.methods.setName("Palm").send({from:accounts[0]});
    const greeting = await Bottle.methods.getGreeting().call();

    console.log(greeting);
    });
}

async function run() {
    try {
        await web3Contract();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Your error is this - ' , err);
    } finally {
        console.log('finally');
    }
}

run();
```

getGreeting().call() is giving me this error. I tried numerous different ways and been stuck on here for hours. Not to sure what to do. https://gyazo.com/81970d03c1380cd513998f25deef9e40

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly combining `await` and the callback function (in your case `function(result) {}`).

Since you're using `await`, it never reaches the callback function, and the returned `Promise` is resolved by the `await` statement.

In the context of your code, it makes more sense to return the value from the `await` and then print it.

```
// remove the callback function
const greeting = await Bottle.methods.getGreeting.call();
console.log(greeting);
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your time. I edited my code and now it is giving me this new error.

Comment: The new error is unrelated to the original issue (not printing the output). A call can revert for a number of reasons, including: 1) There's no contract on the called address, 2) Incorrect ABI (return value could not be parsed), 3) The contract threw an exception (by failing `require()` statement, disallowed arithmetic operation, failing an internal call to other contract because of any reason 1-3, ...). Please ask a separate question where you show steps to reproduce the issue including relevant parts of the contract source code, and verify that you're calling it on a correct address, etc.

Comment: I verified in ganache and it's showing the transactions going through. The address is correct as well. The ABI is correct as well cause I can console.log it just fine and it'll show the json. Also if i just use getGreeting.call() instead of getGreeting().call() it will return a big object of the contract.